# Is there a way to detect that code is running in colaboratory as opposed to "classic jupyter"

Tags: scala, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

Does anyone know if there is a way to programatically determine that we're running in colaboratory as opposed to "classic jupyter"?

Following [this great article about using Scala on Colaboratory](https://medium.com/@shadaj/machine-learning-with-scala-in-google-colaboratory-e6f1661f1c88), I tried using plotly.

However, I ran into [this issue](https://github.com/alexarchambault/plotly-scala/issues/77). Although I found a work around (as detailed in the issue). One of the comments suggests that there is a generic work around that could be applied if our code could detect that it was running in Colaboratory.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3):

There are several module imports typical of Colab. For example, in Python:

```
import sys
'google.colab' in sys.modules
```

Comment: I'm hoping to find something that I could include in an "if statement" so that we can trigger a different behavior based on that runtime; because apparently that's what's needed for https://plot.ly/scala/ to run properly in it.